# Can´t use toLocaleString() on a prop in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I´ve tried everything, but I can´t make this work, when I try to execute the method on the prop the app breaks, this is the only place where this happens, as I have used this method in other parts of the app (and it works). I think the problem is that the method is being executed before the data is rendered.

Here is the code:

```
const ItemDetail = ({data}) => {
  
  const[goToCart,setGoToCart]=useState(false);

  const {addProduct} = useCartContext()

  const onAdd=(value)=>{
    value > 0 && setGoToCart(true);
    addProduct(data, value)
  }


  return (
    <div className='itemDetailBox'>
        <div>
            <img src={data.img_url} className='itemDetailImg' alt="Imagen de producto"></img>
        </div>
        <div className='ItemDetailTextBox'>
            <h2 className='itemDetailTitle'>{data.title}</h2>
            <p className='itemDetailPrice'>${data.price.toLocaleString()}</p>
            <p className='ietmDetailDescription'>{data.description}</p>
            {
              goToCart ?  <><Link to='/'> <button className='btn'>Seguir Comprando</button></Link><Link to='/cart'> <button className='btn'>Finalizar Compra</button></Link></> : <ItemCount initial={1} stock={10} onAdd={onAdd}/>
            }
       </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And here is the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')"

And this is the Parent Element:

```
const ItemDetailContainer = () => {

  const [product,setProduct]= useState([])

  const {id} = useParams();
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const querydb = getFirestore();
    const querydoc = doc(querydb, 'products', id);
    getDoc(querydoc)
      .then(res=> setProduct({id:res.id, ...res.data()}))
      .then (console.log(product))
  },[])
  
  return (
          <div>
            <ItemDetail data = {product}/>
          </div>
      )
}

export default ItemDetailContainer
```

Comment: Change `${data.price.toLocaleString()}` to `${data?.price?.toLocaleString() || ''}` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

So you’re kind of on the right lines when you say it’s executing before the data is rendered.

The child component is assuming it’s always going to be ran with valid `data` props, however on the first pass there is no data, it’s still fetching. `toLocaleString` is expecting `price` to exist, because it doesn’t exist for a moment, it errors.

You can get around this a couple of ways:

1. In your parent component, if data doesn’t exist, then don’t return the child component yet, return null.
2. Or add the check in the child component, if data doesn’t exist, return null.

You could go a step further and instead of returning null, return some kind of loading/skeleton component so the user knows something is happening and the full component doesn’t just pop into the UI once ready.